# Determine if $ R=\{(x,y)\mid x\geq y^{2})$ is antisymmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

as the title says I am trying to prove if the relation in quesiton is anti-symmetric or not with respect ot the domain of integers. Can the following procedure be applied?

$R$ is antisymmetric if for every integer $x,y$, if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$, then $x=y$.

We could try to give a direct proof of this:

if $(x,y)\in R$, then $x\geq y^{2}$ so $x\geq y$. Since $(y,x)\in R$ by assumption, then $y\geq x^{2}$ so $y\geq x$.

But if $y\geq x$ and $x\geq y$, then $x=y$. So the relation is anti-symmetric

Comment: Looks good to me. What are your doubts about the proof?

Comment: I see a major gap in the step, if $x\ge y^2$ then $x\ge y$.  Perhaps a counterexample is of interest?

Comment: @hardmath: Note that the question is about a relation on the *integers.*

Comment: @MartinR thanks, I was just wondering if the proof method were correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is correct.

---

*Mostly just posting this to get this out of the unanswered queue. Posting as Community Wiki in particular since I have nothing further to add.*